# Problem on the totient function and the divisor function

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

I stumbled upon a problem in my number theory class regarding the divisor function $d(n)$ and the totient function $\phi(n)$, where the problem states:

Does there exist a constant $C$ such that $\frac{\phi(d(n))}{d(\phi(n))}\le C$ ?

I already know how to solve this problem and the answer seems to be "No", however i am more interested in the motive behind this question. if this problem is important, then why is it important to prove such constants exist or does not exist ? What are the implications for when it does exist or doesnt exist?

Could anyone give me an elaborate explanation to this ?

Comment: Is $d(n)$ the divisor-sum function or the number of positive divisors of $n$ ? If it is the first, it is usually written as $\sigma(n)$ , the latter usually as $\tau(n)$

Comment: It represents the number of positive divisors of $n$ in the text i am using.

Comment: There is no special "motive". Euler's totient function of $d(n)$ simply is not less than a constant multiple of the number of divisors of $\phi(n)$. The importance might be that you get used to the arithmetic functions and their properties. Could you add your reasonings for the "NO"?

Comment: What text are you using, and what page has this?

Comment: Oh the text is the set of classroom notes my professor uses for his lectures. The proof is a long proof using the prime number theorem and application of inequalities to construct the bounds which he has outlined in his notes. The solution is neat, but i just dont get why this might be interesting to solve to first place, or is it just one of those exercises without any interesting motive ?